# Displaying only a single forecast with autoplot in the R forecast package

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

The autoplot function works great for 2 or more forecasts and will display the data, forecast, and forecast prediction interval

```
library(forecast)
austres %>% hw(2) %>% autoplot()
```

However, for a single forecast, it will giving the following message

```
 austres %>% hw(1) %>% autoplot()

 geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to 
 adjust the group aesthetic?
```

A plot still shows up, but without the forecast and PI band

Is this a ggplot2 or a forecast issue?

Comment: Looks like a `forecast` issue. I've logged it at https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/779

Comment: Plotting a single forecast works just fine with the regular plot function, but the auto throws the error (for anyone reading this before fix). I appreciate you logging this @RobHyndman!